# Give different ID to each element in for loop in PhP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, loops

[This is my output, clicking like button should add +1 to the likes column in MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSnjL.png) .

I use a while loop to iterate buttons

For example, the "button" is displayed multiple times in the picture below. I have a tag in the while loop, so it outputs the button several times. And that name comes from the database.

**MY Question**. All the buttons in the will have the same ID. Currently, the user can only click the first button. I would like to give each element a different ID if possible. Then I would like to use jQuery to add a click event. So, if I click on the 4th button, the like count for that comment should be increased.

**What I need.**
How I can assign a different ID to each element in the far loop, so it does only make the first Image clickable but instead all elements' clickables?

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
        <div class="single-item">
             <div class="cmt_user"><div class="circle2">
                  <h5>
                     <?php
                         $name = $row['name'];
                         $f_letter = strtoupper($name[0]);
                         echo $f_letter; 
                      ?>
                  </h5>
                  </div>
                      <h4><a href=""><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></h4>
                  </div>
                       <p><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></p><div class="lcr">
                       <ul>
                           <li id = "modified" >  </li>
                       </ul>
                       <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" class="form">
                           <button onclick="imageClick(<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?>)" name="like" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="like_btn"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Like</button>
                       </form>
```

this is Php Code to insert likes count

```
<?php
     $like = $_POST['like'];
     if($like){
            $sql = "UPDATE comments set likes = likes + 1 where id = '".$row['id']."'"; 
            echo $sql;
            $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
     }
         
?>
```

Comment: Your code is ripe open for SQL injection.

Comment: "Indexed ids" are not a solution to your problem. Use classes, robust DOM structure and event delegation instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's really simple. do it like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
        <div class="single-item">
             <div class="cmt_user"><div class="circle2">
                  <h5>
                     <?php
                         $name = $row['name'];
                         $f_letter = strtoupper($name[0]);
                         echo $f_letter; 
                      ?>
                  </h5>
                  </div>
                      <h4><a href=""><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></h4>
                  </div>
                       <p><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></p><div class="lcr">
                       <ul>
                           <li id = "modified" >  </li>
                       </ul>
                       <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" class="form">
                            <input name="like" value="1"> 
                            <input name="row_id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"> 
                           <button class="like_btn"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Like</button>
                       </form>
```

And get POST values like this

```
<?php
     $like = $_POST['like'];
     $row_id = $_POST['row_id'];
     if(isset($like) && $like == 1){
            $sql = "UPDATE comments set likes = likes + 1 where id = '".$row_id."'"; 
            echo $sql;
            $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
     }
         
?>
```

Comment: That will actually increase the like count for every button, but I need specifically for each and every button while looping.

Comment: I have changed the answer, this will solve your problem

Comment: Your code might be ok for a collage assignment or something, but don't write code like this if you are planning to host this on internet. your code is vulnerable and easy to hack. You can use a framework like Laravel or Codeigniter to make it more secure.